# Should I Use a Temp Table To Optimize?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a somewhat complex query that I need to access for the IDs in order to delete from multiple tables, something along the lines of:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN ( -- Query here -- )
DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE ID IN ( -- Query here -- )
```

Would selecting the query into a temp table be more efficient than writing out the entire query twice, or is it just visually cleaner?

```
SELECT ( -- Query here -- ) INTO #Temp 
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN ( SELECT * FROM #Temp )
DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE ID IN ( SELECT * FROM #Temp )
```

Also, am open to other suggestions that I may have overlooked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only real answer with any question about query performance is "try it and see", as it depends on so many factors that there is almost never an answer that is correct for every case. So: try it and see, using things like `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON` and getting query plans. There are cases where simply repeating the query might win out over filling a temp table, and there are cases where a temp table wins (and there are cases where a temp table wins but only after creating an index on it).

Comment: Without seeing your query plans there is no way we could answer this. We also need to see your tables and indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely agree with Jeroen Mostert. Try it and see. You could although try to use CTE for deletion or table variables and select distinct values of IDs there in case you have no distinct values of IDs in your query. And if you have a lot of data to delete, try to create additional indexes in temp table.

Comment: A CTE will not make any difference versus the `IN(<query>)` construction IMHO. But yeah, simply try it out, look at the execution plan and see what happens. If the cost of the query is (higher) than the delete, doing it just once into a #temp table and then using that result for both DELETE's will be advisable. If it's the other way around... well, I'd probably still do it for improved readability and maintainability tbh =)

Comment: Yep, completely agree with you. And we could use "IF EXISTS" in WHERE to optimize DELETE query too.